# Every URL is redirected to Gitlab page

Tags: python, django, nginx, digital-ocean, gitlab-ci

I wanted to have Gitlab CI and Django in digital ocean. I've created a droplet and configured the Gitlab installation with the following settings:

```
external_url = "http:/lab.###.com/"

# gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from'] = "gitlab@example.com"
# gitlab_rails['gitlab_support_email'] = "support@example.com"

# gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
# gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "smtp.server"
# gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 465
# gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "smtp user"
# gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = "smtp password"
# gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "example.com"
# gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "login"
# gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
# gitlab_rails['smtp_openssl_verify_mode'] = 'peer'

# nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = false
# nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.crt"
# nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.key"
```

and here is my nginx settings

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 150.200.##.## abc.com www.abc.com;
    client_max_body_size 50M;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/root/eatplus-django;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        # proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_connect_timeout 30;
        proxy_read_timeout 30;
    }
}
```

When I enter lab.##.com, I am redirected to Gitlab which is expected but when entering IP address and www.###.com I am still redirected to Gitlab page which is unexpected behavior. How do i resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

In your nginx config, change your `server_name` config to

```
server_name lab.###.com;
```

In that way, nginx will serve your gitlab page only under the `lab.###.com` subdomain.

Comment: Cant we have separate url for gitlab and django?

Comment: Yes, you can! Just make sure that the server config with the Django upstream has all the domains set and/or is marked as `default_server`.

Comment: Can you show me an example, please? lab.###.com for gitlab and www.###.com to serve django